# Regarding HEIF/ISO-BMFF parsing

Tags: image, parsing, video, mp4, heif

In HEIF, or generally any ISO-BMFF file, does any know how to use pitm box in root meta box to parse the main image?

For example, the documents say the ID of the main image is stored in the pitm box, but when I obtain that ID and find the appropriate one in iloc box, it did not point to a valid offset and length.

Or should I search for other boxes for where to find the main image's media stream? Does anyone know what I've done incorrectly?

Comment: Upload and give link to your test image so check and advise. Also for _"where to find the main image's media stream?"_ that should be in `mdat` section.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't upload the image due to content/copyright concerns. However, I also wanted to ask how I can find the slice headers in a HEIF file. In the hvcC box, only VPS, SPS, and PPS are there. Do you or anyone else have any clue? Thanks in advance.